# jQuery clicked element AppendTo another Div in a each function

Tags: jquery

I will build a Stacked Images Carousel like this https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/3D-Card-Carousel-Rotator-With-jQuery-CSS3/

The JS Code (https://www.jqueryscript.net/rotator/3D-Card-Carousel-Rotator-With-jQuery-CSS3.html) is build to use the Carousel just one time in a page.

But I will use it more than one time on the same page. So I have to rewrite the script. I try this with jquery and an each click function. My CSS is working well but i have trouble to appendTo the clicked Element to my wrapper div.

My markup

```
<div class="stackimages-items">
    <div class="stackimages-item">
        <img src="image-001.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="stackimages-item">
        <img src="image-002.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="stackimages-item">
        <img src="image-003.jpg">
    </div>
</div>
```

This is how it will work, but only when i will use the Carousel one time in a page.

```
$('.stackimages-item').click(function() {
    $('.stackimages-item:first-child').fadeOut(400, 'swing', function() {
        $('.stackimages-item:first-child').appendTo('.stackimages-items').hide();
    }).fadeIn(400, 'swing');
});
```

And this is what I try to use it more than one time in a page. But it will not append it to my wrapper (stackimages-items).

```
$('.stackimages-item').click(function(e) {
    $(this).find(':first-child').fadeOut(400, 'swing', function() {
        $(this).appendTo('.stackimages-items').hide();
    }).fadeIn(400, 'swing');
});
```

What did i wrong? Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: `$(this).find(':first-child')` -> find looks for child items - the original equivalent would have been `$(".stackimages-item :first-child")` - but it's not.  Change to `$(this).filter(':first-child')` or `$(this).first()`

Comment: Also, `$(this).appendTo('.stackimages-items')` will append to *all* .stackimages-items, likely duplicating your image.   Probably want `$(this).appendTo($(this).closest('.stackimages-items')).hide();`

Comment: Thanks for explanation, perfect now it is working as expected with this.

$('.stackimages-item').click(function(e) {
 $(this).filter(':first-child').fadeOut(400, 'swing', function() {
  $(this).appendTo($(this).closest('.stackimages-items')).hide();
 }).fadeIn(400, 'swing');
});

Thanks very very much (y)

Answer (score 0):

Your attempt with `$(this).find(':first-child')`
would have had an original equivalent of

```
$(".stackimages-item :first-child")
```

The equivalent of `.stackimages-item:first-child` is

```
$(this).filter(':first-child') 
//or 
$(this).first()
```

Secondly: `$(this).appendTo('.stackimages-items')` will append to all `.stackimages-items`, likely duplicating your image across each stack.

Instead you'll want to use:

```
$(this).appendTo($(this).closest('.stackimages-items')).hide();
```

Comment: Thanks for explanation, perfect now it is working as expected with your help. Thanks you very much